# How to pass props though hoc function to child component as a class state name

Tags: reactjs

Passing props through Hoc function, and store this props as a class state name, then recall it to the child component. Something like this:

```
export const withHoc = ({ Drawer, anchor }) => class WithHoc extends Component {
  state = {
    this.props.anchor: false
  }
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer open={this.state.anchor} />
    )
  }
}
```

If the anchor props is 'left', the `state = { left: false }`, and `<Drawer open=false />`.

Comment: Looks like name is always going to be `false` every time (I'm assuming that name is a required prop,) Maybe I'm overlooking something. What's the reason for keeping _'state'_ in the HOC?

Comment: I using the material ui drawer component, and I want to make this component as a Hoc function, so it is convenient to add to other component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initializing state as a class variable means that you're not able to reference the instance of the HOC.

However, since `anchor` is destructured from the argument passed to the HOC, it can be referenced and set in state as a computed property.

```
export const withHoc = ({ anchor }) =>
  class WithHoc extends Component {
    state = {
      [anchor]: false
    }

    //...
    render() {
      return <Drawer open={this.state.anchor} />
    }
  }
```